# Left aligning icons in a Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu where I'd like an icon to appear to the left of the text, similar to how a menu item might appear in a dropdown of a typical desktop application.

By default, there appears to be a gutter to the left of the icon, which pushes it further to the right than I'd like. I'm able to resolve this by adding the CSS: `i { margin-left: -15px; }`. But I'm afraid this absolute positioning might affect the responsiveness.

Is there a way of achieving this effect using existing Bootstrap classes?

The following snippet will hopefully demonstrate what I mean:

```css
i {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></i> Item 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: no worries this won't affect the responsiveness, go ahead with it

Comment: one thing to worry about, you have to add a more specified rule to let the css affect only the icons inside a dropdown e.g. `.dropdown-menu li a i`

Comment: @AlaaMh Thank you for the tip!

Comment: you're most welcome bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to give `margin-left:-15px` then you can also decrease `padding-left` of `a` element like this:

```
.btn-group .dropdown-menu > li > a{
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```css
.btn-group .dropdown-menu > li > a{
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></i> Item 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```